# Did contestant keep the items they filled in their trolleys?

Tags: reality-tv, dales-supermarket-sweep

I was just wondering something For every contestant on *Dale's Supermarket Sweep*, did they keep the items that they filled in their trolleys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dale%27s_Supermarket_Sweep) suggests **NO**.

They receive a cash equivalent of the goods instead.

> The team with the higher Big Sweep total (added with their sub total from bonuses and previous rounds) keeps their money and advances to the Super Sweep. The team has 60 seconds to find the £2,000 prize (£5,000 in the revived version), by solving three clues.
>
> The first clue is given by Dale and time doesn't start until the clue has been read. The team must find the item from the clue to get the next clue. The second clue leads the contestants to the final item, behind which the money is found.
>
> As with the US version, the team has to find all three items and have their hands on the money before time expires. **If they don't, they only leave with the cash equivalent of the value of the goods in their trolley.**